# Permutation and combination of layers with specific thickness

Tags: combinatorics

Hiii,
I don't even know it is the right place to ask, But please enlighten this beginner with some ideas related to permutation and combinations (Also help me,If this problem is not under this category).

I want to divide 5 km depth with different horizontal layers, The individual layers thickness could be 1,2,3,4,5 kms. So how many combinations could I make?

eg:

````
1 1 1 1 1 

.
.
1 1 1 2
.
.
2 2 1
2 1 2
etc..
```
````

Comment: Your second example does not make sense since $2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10 \neq 5$.  If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $5$.

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake, Now corrected. thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to MSE. The question that you've asked refers to the number of compositions of 5. For each positive integer, $N$, there are $2^{n-1}$ distinct compositions. In the case of the question, our integer is 5. So, the number of compositions is given by $2^4$, which is $16$. For your interest, I have included them below.

5

4 + 1

3 + 2

3 + 1 + 1

2 + 3

2 + 2 + 1

2 + 1 + 2

2 + 1 + 1 + 1

1 + 4

1 + 3 + 1

1 + 2 + 2

1 + 2 + 1 + 1

1 + 1 + 3

1 + 1 + 2 + 1

1 + 1 + 1 + 2

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Comment: so how it will change, if there is a constrain in the individual layer thickness? Like if only 1,2 and 3 kms is allowed to make the combinations, how the formula will change? and could you suggest some materials to understand more about this?

Comment: Have you followed the link in Taussig's comment, VGB?

Comment: @VGB $5$ can only be composed $3$ ways including the digits $4,5$. These are $5, 4+1, 1+4$. Therefore, there are $13$ ways to compose $5$ using only the digits $1,2,3$

Comment: @LogLogLogLogx is there a general formula to derive these combinations If the sum and the individual numbers are provided?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, I am going through that.

Comment: Somewhat same question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80499/how-to-get-number-of-combinations-from-given-set-of-numbers-to-result-a-given-su